# API para que Android pueda interactuar con WhatsApp

Tags: android

La idea inicial es conectar o que una aplicación `Android` para que pueda interactuar con `WhatsApp` (por ejemplo mandar texto a WhatsApp, activar o desactivar funciones para un usuario determinado ect).

He buscado alguna `API` para esta tarea pero no he podido encontrar ninguna, y la que encontré quizás este abandonada (https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) y no es oficial.

¿Existe alguna API oficial para ello?.

Por otro lado la alternativa que estoy usando es la siguiente (para el envio de texto):

Después de mirar [este link](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012) (en inglés)

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();

sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Más o menos sería algo así:

```
public void enviarMsgApp(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent .setType("text/plain");
    String texto = "Mensaje para enviar aqui";
    intent .setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (intent != null) {
        intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, texto);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, texto));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Nooo whatsapp, whatsapp man",  
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                       .show();
    }
}
```

*Existe alguna alternativa para poder modificar el "comportamiento" de WhatsApp sobre un usuario.*

Por ejemplo algo así como que se le diga a la aplicación (que se esta creando) el nombre del usuario, y esta aplicación puede hacer los cambios sobre ese usuario. por ejemplo cambiar la foto que se muestra, silenciar etc, **aunque para ello** tenga que solicitar permisos a el usuario o que el mismo `WhatsApp` alerte al usuario de que se esta intentado realizar un ajuste y este tenga que autorizarlo o algo así.

### Pseudo code:

```
public void cambiarFotoApp(View view, String nombreUsuario) {
        //..    
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //..

        intent .setPackage("com.whatsapp"); 
        //..
        //cambiarFoto(nombreUsuario, jpgNuevaFoto); 
}
```

Comment: Debes tener cuidado, porque lo mas probable es que tu aplicación sea baneada, mientras ellos no proporcionen un medio oficial para interactuar es considerado una afectación a un servicio de terceros. Eso a menos que solo desees distribuirla en el mercado negro claro.

Comment: @Gemasoft  gracias por tu comentario, estaba buscando informacion para saber que aplicacion usar estaba entre Whatsapp y otras, pero estaba buscando informacion antes de decidirme cual usar, por cosas como estas no encontrarme con problemas, que te hacen cambiar el enfoque de tu app, en este caso seria que no hay una API oficial y tener que rescribir codigo para adaptarlo, gracias por la info sobre ser baneada, por cosas asi queria una oficial pero se agradece el comentario Saludos

Comment: Yo intento buscar cómo lo consigue el pushbullet, ya que cuando recibes un whatss, lo detecta y con la extención de chrome en el desktop puedes responder el mesaje, es decir alguna forma se puede.

Answer (score 7):

Por el momento no hay ningún API oficial para interactuar con la aplicación más allá del ejemplo que muestras para enviar un mensaje.

Durante un tiempo una opción viable era [WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) pero el autor tuvo problemas legales por este repositorio y abandonó el desarrollo.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor solución que puedes usar, es mediante el link:

**"whatsapp://send?phone=59165868685&text=Este es el mensaje a cambiar"**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String uri = "whatsapp://send?phone=" + "codigo pais + tu numero ej: 59165868685" + "&text=" + "Este es el mensaje para enviar";
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

También podrías utilizar la siguiente URL que permite abrir la aplicación directamente para enviar al número telefónico destino:

`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=59177242524`

Hay que incluir el código del país en el número.

- 591 código del país
- 77242524 número telefónico

Podría ser muy útil por ejemplo cuando se esta creando una pantalla de contacto en la aplicación y con un botón "Contáctame" abrir WhatsApp directo para escribir.

Comment: Lo he probado pero me dice "Phone number shared via url is invalid" , no necesitara algún tipo de permiso para usar esta API?

Answer (score 0):

Esto podrías hacerlo de cierta manera usando un servicio de accesibilidad en Android pero sí tendrías que tener la aplicación oficial instalada, no puedo explicarte más a fondo porque quedaría mega larga mi respuesta Así que te sugiero entrar a la sección de accesibilidad de Android developers.
Básicamente el principio se basaría en extraer información de las notificaciones usando el servicio de accesibilidad además de interactuar mediante intents explícitos directamente con la aplicación de WhatsApp