# llamada a un numero de teléfono por whatsapp.

Tags: java, android, android-studio, whatsapp

En android Studio ...como puedo hacer que al momento de presionar un botón en mi activity este me haga una llamada a un numero de teléfono por whatsapp.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [API para que Android pueda interactuar con WhatsApp](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2386/api-para-que-android-pueda-interactuar-con-whatsapp)

Comment: como es posible que tu pregunta acabe cerrada como duplicada (a pesar de no serlo estrictamente), he buscado en internet con "whatsapp call intent android" y encontre esta respuesta en ingles que explica como hacerlo, si logras dar con la solucion y no han cerrado la pregunta aun, por favor publica lo que has logrado. Saludos. RTA: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38674897/2573335

Answer (score 1):

Realizar llamada no es posible no existe un intent para tal acción, aún no es soportado.

Unicamente puedes enviar mensaje:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6690/95